# Как заменить одну букву из массива строк на другую JS

Tags: javascript, массивы, строки

Нужно написать код, в котором:

1. Первый символ в строке должен быть преобразован в код ASCII
2. Заменить вторую букву слова на последнюю

Я сделал первую часть, но ума не приложу как мне в моем коде реализовать вторую часть.
Код:

```js
const str = "hello world"
const encryptThis = ((text) => {
    const getArray = text.split(' ')
    const getNewArr = []
    getArray.forEach(element => {
        const getFires = element[0].charCodeAt() + element.slice(1)
        getNewArr.push(getFires)
    })
    return getNewArr.join(' ') // 104ello 119orld, результат должен быть: "104olle 119drlo"
})

console.log(encryptThis(str))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вытаскиваем из строки нужные нам значения и позже склеиваем.

> В строках можно обратиться к символу по его **индексу**. Так же у строк есть метод **length**, который возвращает длину строки

Воспользуемся этими методами:

```js
const str = "hello world"
const encryptThis = ((text) => {
  const getArray = text.split(' ')
  const getNewArr = [];
  getArray.forEach(element => {
    const char = element[0].charCodeAt();
    const sec = element[1]; // Сохраняем вторую букву
    const last = element.slice(-1); // Сохраняем последнюю букву
    // Склеиваем в строку полученный результат в нужном порядке
    getNewArr.push(char + last + element.slice(2, -1) + sec);
  })
  return getNewArr.join(' ') // 104ello 119orld, результат должен быть: "104olle 119drlo"
})

console.log(encryptThis(str));
```

Comment: Страшные вещи пишите... Можно ведь так: `slice(2, -1)` :)

Comment: @ΝNL993 И то верно! Поправил ) Тогда уж и поиск последнего символа строки переведем на `slice`