# как поменять первый и последний символ строки js?

Tags: javascript

попытался что то сделать, спрашивал. по итогу вот что имею

```js
let str = prompt('Введите строку');
let fir = str[0];
let last = str[str.lenght - 1];
const swap = () => {
  last = str[0]
  fir = str[str.lenght - 1]
}
swap()
```

Comment: Может [поможет это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1473173/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%83-%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b2%d1%83-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d1%83%d1%8e-js/1473180#1473180)

Answer (score 2):

Ну во-первый, у вас очепятка не `lenght`, а `length`.

Во-вторых, вы сможете только получить символ по его индексу в строке, а вот чтобы записать туда, требуется другой подход.. (например такой - [String.prototype.replaceAt()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1431113/7692602))

Ну и в третьих, я бы при работе со строками лучше б регулярку заюзал, проще же:

```js
// let str = prompt('Введите строку');
const swap = str => str.replace(/^(.)(.+)(.)$/, '$3$2$1');

console.log(swap('Hello'));
console.log(swap('World'));
console.log(swap('Какой-то другой текст'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let str = 'Введите строку';

const swap = (str) =>  str[str.length-1] + str.slice(1, str.length-1) + str[0];

console.log(swap(str));
```

Answer (score 0):

Первое что нужно помнить, это то что строки неизменяемая структура данных. А буквы поменять можно вот так, как вариант:

```js
let str = prompt('Введите строку');

const swap = (str) => {
  let result = "";
  const fir = str[0];
  result = str[str.length - 1];
  for (let i = 1, n = str.length - 1; i < n; ++i) {
    result += str[i];
  }
  return result += fir;
}
console.log(swap(str));
```